# could not find driver on .... Laravel App 10.14.1, PHP 8.2.0

Tags: laravel-10, php-8.2

i am developing the laravel app. At localhost, everything ok. But when i deploy to serve. The error  was appear. Someone help me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifef3.png)

i am trying to slove this problem. I saw phpmyadmin that using maria, and the real serve using mysql serve. Is the problem here ?